# Missing attribute in JUnit report

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5, junit-runner

When I look the JUnit xsd into the JUnit project https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/platform-tests/src/test/resources/jenkins-junit.xsd

I see that the ***skipped*** attribute is not present into the ***testsuites*** node.
Only the ***disabled*** is present

I'm wondering that ***testsuites*** node will group all results of différent ***testsuite*** and cumulate the skipped attribute of all testsuite (if present)

Do you know the reason of this ?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this is that **skipped** category it's a legacy from previous JUnit versions used to group `@Ignore` annotated elements. JUnit5, to which you referring, uses `@Disabled` annotation for such purpose, therefore **disabled** category goes here. Please see [Official JUnit5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) for more info

Comment: do you mean that ***skipped*** category is deprecated from JUnit5 ?